# Modify returned data from findOne function

Tags: sequelize.js

I created functions for get config with db. I use a sequelize on my server.

```
async function getConfig(country) {
    return await db.config.findOne({
        where: { id: 1 },
        include: [
            {
                model: db.domain,
                attributes: ['domain'],
                as: 'domain',
                where: {
                    country_code: country,
                    isActive: true,
                },
            },
            {
                model: db.currency,
                attributes: ['id', 'code'],
            },
            {
                model: db.task,
                attributes: ['name'],
                as: 'name',
                where: {
                    isActive: true,
                },
            },
        ],
    });
}
```

This functions return a result.

```
"result": {
        "id": 1,
        "is_show": false,
        "version": "1.4.5",
        "domain": [
            {
                "domain": "https://....."
            }
        ],
        "currencies": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "code": "USD",
                "symbol": "$",
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "code": "USD",
                "symbol": "$",
            }
        ],
        "name": [
            {
                "name": 123
            }
        ]
    }
```

I need to modify this result and I want to get this result

```
"result": {
        "id": 1,
        "is_show": false,
        "version": "1.4.5",
        "domain": "https://.....",  
        "currencies": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "code": "USD",
                "symbol": "$",
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "code": "USD",
                "symbol": "$",
            }
        ],
        "name": 123,
    }
```

I tried to do it use an operator `raw: true`. But it was unsuccessful.

```
           {
                model: db.task,
                attributes: ['name'],
                as: 'name',
                raw: true,
                where: {
                    isActive: true,
                },
            },
```

How can I do it?

---

Response

```
"result": {
        "id": 1,
        "is_show": false,
        "version": "1.4.5",
        "domain": [
            {
                "0": "h",
                "1": "t",
                "2": "t",
                "3": "p",
                "4": "s",
                "5": ":",
                "6": "/",
                "7": "/",
                "8": ".",
                "9": ".",
                "10": ".",
                "11": ".",
                "12": "."
            }
        ],
        "currencies": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "code": "USD",
                "symbol": "$",
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "code": "USD",
                "symbol": "$",
            }
        ],
        "name": [
            {
                "name": 123
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get some field from an included model as an attribute of a main model you can add it to the main `attributes` option like this (look at `domain` below):

```
return await db.config.findOne({
        where: { id: 1 },
        attributes: { include: [[sequelize.col('domain.domain'), 'domain']] },
        include: [
            {
                model: db.domain,
                attributes: [],
                as: 'domain',
                where: {
                    country_code: country,
                    isActive: true,
                },
            },
            {
                model: db.currency,
                attributes: ['id', 'code'],
            },
            {
                model: db.task,
                attributes: ['name'],
                as: 'name',
                where: {
                    isActive: true,
                },
            },
        ],
    });
```

Comment: I got an error `[ERROR] default - TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined`

Comment: I fixed `sequelize.col` call

Comment: I got a response, but it's wrong. I added response in the end my question

Comment: Oh, wait! `domain` is an array! How you supposed to represent it only by one string?

Comment: That's why I came here. The domain field will always contain one domain from the database, and the database will contain an array of domains.. Can this be implemented?

Comment: So one `config` record is linked with several records of `domain`, right?

Comment: And how should mapped `domain` field like like considering several source records? A string with a list of domains separated by comma?

Comment: No. There can be only one domain when I request a config from the database. Because only one can be an active domain and therefore I search for it by the `isActive` field

Comment: In this case you can either use `sequelize.literal` with a subquery instead of `sequelize.col` or change an association from `hasMany` or `hasOne` or add such association as a separate one with an alias